# JS why is the output of my code 10x undefined?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass 10 different objects into a function (logObjekt) so that I can console.log the property name which is setup inside all objects.

Instead of having to write 10 lines of code to make this possible I am using a for loop to increment each name that's going to be passed to the function, I made this possible because all objects starts with "objekt".

When I debug this everything looks good and I get the result "object1, object2 ... and so on" when JS coerce the int to string and combine the two. So at first glance I thought iI got a good solution but when I implemented the solution I got 10x undefined instead of 10 values from the objects.

```js
var objekt1  = { "name": "value1" };
var objekt2  = { "name": "value2" };
var objekt3  = { "name": "value3" };
var objekt4  = { "name": "value4" };
var objekt5  = { "name": "value5" };
var objekt6  = { "name": "value6" };
var objekt7  = { "name": "value7" };
var objekt8  = { "name": "value8" };
var objekt9  = { "name": "value9" };
var objekt10 = { "name": "value10" };

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  logObjekt("objekt" + i);
};

function logObjekt(objekt) {
  console.log(objekt.name)
};
```

I expect to log properties in the objects thats called "name".

Right now to actual result is 10x undefined.

Comment: Because you are passing a **string** value to `logObject`, and strings don't have a `.name` property.

Comment: What you really want is to use an array of objects, which you can easily access by index. Don't use enumerated variable names.

Comment: It needs to be an object data-type on the left side of . like this:

    object.property

is that the problem, that i currently is passing string.property?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript for better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access global variables with a variable name, you *could* (but in your case shouldn't, see below first snippet) use the square bracket syntax.

```js
var objekt1 = {
  "name": "value1"
};

var objekt2 = {
  "name": "value2"
};

var objekt3 = {
  "name": "value3"
};

var objekt4 = {
  "name": "value4"
};

var objekt5 = {
  "name": "value5"
};

var objekt6 = {
  "name": "value6"
};

var objekt7 = {
  "name": "value7"
};

var objekt8 = {
  "name": "value8"
};

var objekt9 = {
  "name": "value9"
};

var objekt10 = {
  "name": "value10"
};

var i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  logObjekt(window["objekt" + i]);
};

function logObjekt(objekt) {
  console.log(objekt.name)
};
```

Please note that I showed this only to show how to do it if need be.

By no means ***should*** you do it that way. As others have mentioned already, instead put your objects into an array:

```js
var objekt = [{
  "name": "value1"
}, {
  "name": "value2"
}, {
  "name": "value3"
}, {
  "name": "value4"
}, {
  "name": "value5"
}, {
  "name": "value6"
}, {
  "name": "value7"
}, {
  "name": "value8"
}, {
  "name": "value9"
}, {
  "name": "value10"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < objekt.length; i++) {
  logObjekt(objekt[i]);
};

function logObjekt(objekt) {
  console.log(objekt.name)
};
```

Comment: Of course, as soon as you put this inside a function it's going to fail.

Comment: While this is working, you really should not recommend to use and access global variables.

Comment: @Bergi I was working on exactly that part while you commented.

Comment: In future posts, work on the most relevant part of the answer first, please :-)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for tho, but im glad that i could learn something deeper in the process :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of objects and push to the array in order to loop through the objects and print out the name property.

```
var objectlist = [];
objectlist.push({ "name": "value1"});
objectlist.push({ "name": "value2"});

for(var i = 0; i < objectlist.length; i++)
{
   logObjekt(objectlist[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and answers. Helped me alot to futher my understanding of JS. If i could i whould set all comments as answeers becouse you were all helpful.